# Access RoutePath from Bing Maps AJAX Control

Tags: bing-maps

How can I access the [RoutePath Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312841.aspx) when using the [Bing Maps AJAX Control, Version 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx)?

I've loaded the directions module, calculated directions and called the getRouteResult method of the [DirectionsManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312802.aspx). Unfortunately, it doesn't return the coordinates of the actual route.

Ultimately, I need the coordinates of the shape which makes up the route line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to some help from Microsoft, I've found how RoutePath is exposed. Access RoutePath by:

```
DirectionsManagerObj.getRouteResult().routeLegs[routeLegIndex]
    .subLegs[subLegIndex].routePath;
```

This works great assuming you have two waypoints. Otherwise, you'll need to loop through routeLegs and subLegs to get the entire route.

A routeLeg represents the path through two waypoints. A subLeg represents the path through a stop point and via point (or two via points). The [DirectionsManager Class API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312802.aspx) has more detail on this information.